# Make new line in modal.find().text("String NEWLINE String)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm setting the text in my modal Body with a variable String. In this thing there needs to be a new line but I can't get it to work

I've already tried \n,\r,\r\n,>br> but nothing works. >br> is just written in the string and the rest of those does not show any result at all

```
modal.find(".modal-body p").text("Wollen sie wirklich \"" + fahrt + "\" für ihr Kind buchen?\r\nDer Fahrer Ihres Kindes ist: "+fahrername );
```

Thanks in advance and I hope it's not such a stupid question because I'm still learning :)

Comment: Html ignores some whitespace unless you use a `<pre>` or style it with the pre style.  Otherwise you can use `<br>` or `<p>` tags to create new lines.

Comment: Also `text()` is going to turn every thing you give it into a string.  So if you give it html, the html will show up as literal text.  If you want the html to render, you should use `html()` instead

Comment: thanks, html() worked, would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept it? :D

Comment: FYI, the string you are using would work if you passed it to functions like `alert()` or `confirm()`. Those are system/browser dialogs and they respect the newline characters.

Comment: I know but I think they are quite ugly so I wanted to change them in order to make it more appealing towards the user :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text()` will insert the string you give it into the element(s) as a text node.  Text nodes do not render html, rather their value is literal text.  If you want the value to be rendered as html, you should use the `html()` method.